# Appending QR codes to divs with unique ids

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have written code to generate QR codes n times, (qr text generated on server and placed into `html input`) however there is some problem when appending the result recursively in a div. Here is the code (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#qr_id_create", function() {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        var url = "server/qr_id_create.php?create_qr_id";
        var n = $("#n_qr_codes").val();
        jQuery('#qrcode_top div').html('');

        for (var i=0; i < n; i++) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#qr_id_result").val(data);

                    var value = $("input[name='qr_input']").val();
                    //this is the problem area
                    $("<div />", {id:"code"+i}).appendTo("#qrcode_top");
                    jQuery('#code'+i).qrcode({text:value});
                }
            });             
        }
        $("#qr_id_create").attr("disabled", false);

    });
```

And html:

```
<button id="qr_id_create" class="button">Create QR Code</button>
<div id="qrcode_top"></div> 
<input id="qr_id_result" type="text" name="qr_input" required>
<input id="n_qr_codes" type="text" name="" required>
```

I am trying to append each qr code generated by jquery within the `html div #qrcode_top`, and each qr code inside its own `div` with a unique id. The idea is to later on create a pdf with all the generated qr codes for printing.

The result of this code is all the qr codes appended within the same `div` with the last generated id. For example, if 5 qr codes are to be generated, all the qr codes (`canvas`) are appended in `<div id="code5">`

I am sure the solution is simple. I have tried various versions of the appending code, but maybe overlooked something. Your input would be appreciated.

Comment: Could your add your html? it looks like you need a promise / callback-function

Comment: Replace `var` with `let` in your `for` loop initial state. Using `var` makes the variable global to all iterations, whereas `let` "locks" it for each iteration. This is one of the reason why the use of `var` is considered bad practice now.

Comment: @Seblor Thank you so much, that did the trick! Could you make an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @roelofco I am glad I could help. I would prefer people reading the question I linked, and get your question flagged as duplicate of it to avoid duplicating the answers and to keep StackOverflow clean.

Comment: @Seblor No problem, understood!!